# tomcat 9 start up extremely slow, but /dev/./urandom not working

Tags: linux, tomcat, tomcat9

On linux, Tomcat 9 starts up extremely slow, but /dev/./urandom did not resolve the problem.

After running Tomcat 9 on product machine for 2 months, run very slow for the last few days. Shut it down, but restarting tomcat took 5 minutes instead of 30 seconds.

adding the following to JVM system properties in bin/setenv.sh

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

did not resolve the problem.

### UPDATE:

Web apps respond very slowly too. It takes about 10 seconds for one HTTP response that normally takes 1 seconds. Is this related to JVM?

Comment: Did you check the disk drives? They tend to slow down before a crash.

Comment: You should run some hardware diagnostics to see if your machine is suffering some problems; in addition, you need to make sure your machine has enough free memory to handle it and isn’t swapping.

Comment: restart linux machine: solved.  causes unknown. do all systems need to be restarted every two months?